# ffmpeg showing wrong frame number on drawtext output

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to save each frame as picture with the frame number printed on it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='%{n}':fontsize=72:fontcolor=white:borderw=3:bordercolor=black" -fps_mode vfr "pics\%5d.jpg"
```

It seems to have worked out ok, but when I go throught the pictures about at frame 930 the framecount simply restarts back to 0 and goes counting on from there again. I have tried to regenerate pts option -fflags +genpts to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your specific question? ... `any ideas?` is too vague

Comment: Add `-reinit_filter 0` before `-i` and check

Comment: @jsotola get the number of frames right on the pictures.

Comment: @Gyan Genious, worked. I already new that filter but I tought it was only used when you concat two videos or images with different frame rates together. If you want to put that as an answer I will mark it as solved....Any idea what might cause such things? With most of the videos I use this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no a change in the frame attributes mid-stream, such as resolution or pixel format, then ffmpeg reinitializes the filtergraph because most filters can't cope with varying attributes. Due to reinit, existing filter state is lost, hence the reset of the frame count. You can suppress this by adding `-reinit_filter 0`. Note this won't work for changing audio stream, since no filters can cope with those yet.